# ActionScript 1 calling to JavaScript on IE 10

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, internet-explorer-10

I have a legacy application which is still running on ActionScript 1.  It calls out to several JavaScript methods using fscommand.  However, this doesn't work in IE10.

I have seen that I should use ExternalInterface(), however I haven't been able to actually get that to work in ActionScript 1.

Is there a trick to doing that?  Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExternalInterface is not available in AS1.

But you can try to add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

to enable FScommand

Comment: I had some issues on this at first, but now it seems to work.  Any idea how stable that will be with IE10, and if there is a risk that it will be deprecated in future releases?